# Check box won't check using styling for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a checkbox that is using Kendo UI styling for checkboxes and when I try to check the checkbox, it won't check.

I know I can use a different way to do checkboxes and labels, but this looks ok and I am using their framework anyway

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label for="isAllowViewQuotesInProcess_" class="k-checkbox-label col-md-offset-2">Allow Vender To View Quotes In Progress?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAllowViewQuotesInProcess_" class="k-checkbox">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the input element comes *immediately before* the label element, as detailed [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling#customize-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input type="checkbox" id="isAllowViewQuotesInProcess_" class="k-checkbox">
<label for="isAllowViewQuotesInProcess_" class="k-checkbox-label col-md-offset-2">Allow Vender To View Quotes In Progress?</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link as well, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! There is a lot of useful info in the kendo documentation, but it can be quite difficult to find.